# Logarithmic y-axis in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, linechart, logarithm

I'm working on a financial application that has some quite large numbers.

One of my charts for example is growing from $25,000 to about $20,000,000,000 (exponentially)

Because of this, using any regular chart without log-scale causes the majority of my data to simply "flatline", while it's in fact growing quickly.

Here's an example

(Ignore that it's not set up yet)

[image]

The above linechart was made using [SwiftChart](https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart)

Now I have to be honest, I am not even at this point entirely sure if I'm even allowed to ask a question like this on SO. But I just have no idea where to begin.

After a couple of hours of searching I have not been able to find any libraries, tutorials, sample apps or anything IOS related that features a graph with a logarithmic axis (neither X or Y).

After I couldn't find anything, I realised I'd have to implement this feature on my own. I found the most suitable library for my application, and I've been trying to figure out how I can implement a way to allow the y-scale to be scaled with a log-scale (with the power of 10).

I've done a fair bit of research on how log-scales work, and used them plenty in my university. But I have never actually seen an example of one programmed.

I found one written in JavaScript (I think). But unfortunately I have no experience with web-development and wasn't able to properly translate it :(

I really don't feel comfortable putting someone elses code on SO, but I really have no clue where to begin.

If this isn't allowed, please post a comment, and I'll get rid of it immediately

All credits of this goes to this guy: https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart

Here's the code that I believe is where I need to implement a log-scale.

```
private func drawChart() {

    drawingHeight = bounds.height - bottomInset - topInset
    drawingWidth = bounds.width

    let minMax = getMinMax()
    min = minMax.min
    max = minMax.max

    highlightShapeLayer = nil

    // Remove things before drawing, e.g. when changing orientation

    for view in self.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    for layer in layerStore {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    layerStore.removeAll()

    // Draw content

    for (index, series) in enumerate(self.series) {

        // Separate each line in multiple segments over and below the x axis
        var segments = Chart.segmentLine(series.data as ChartLineSegment)

        for (i, segment) in enumerate(segments) {
            let scaledXValues = scaleValuesOnXAxis( segment.map( { return $0.x } ) )
            let scaledYValues = scaleValuesOnYAxis( segment.map( { return $0.y } ) )

            if series.line {
                drawLine(xValues: scaledXValues, yValues: scaledYValues, seriesIndex: index)
            }
            if series.area {
                drawArea(xValues: scaledXValues, yValues: scaledYValues, seriesIndex: index)
            }
        }
    }

    drawAxes()

    if xLabels != nil || series.count > 0 {
        drawLabelsAndGridOnXAxis()
    }
    if yLabels != nil || series.count > 0 {
        drawLabelsAndGridOnYAxis()
    }

}

// MARK: - Scaling

private func getMinMax() -> (min: ChartPoint, max: ChartPoint) {

    // Start with user-provided values

    var min = (x: minX, y: minY)
    var max = (x: maxX, y: maxY)

    // Check in datasets

    for series in self.series {
        let xValues =  series.data.map( { (point: ChartPoint) -> Float in
            return point.x } )
        let yValues =  series.data.map( { (point: ChartPoint) -> Float in
            return point.y } )

        let newMinX = minElement(xValues)
        let newMinY = minElement(yValues)
        let newMaxX = maxElement(xValues)
        let newMaxY = maxElement(yValues)

        if min.x == nil || newMinX < min.x! { min.x = newMinX }
        if min.y == nil || newMinY < min.y! { min.y = newMinY }
        if max.x == nil || newMaxX > max.x! { max.x = newMaxX }
        if max.y == nil || newMaxY > max.y! { max.y = newMaxY }
    }

    // Check in labels

    if xLabels != nil {
        let newMinX = minElement(xLabels!)
        let newMaxX = maxElement(xLabels!)
        if min.x == nil || newMinX < min.x { min.x = newMinX }
        if max.x == nil || newMaxX > max.x { max.x = newMaxX }
    }

    if yLabels != nil {
        let newMinY = minElement(yLabels!)
        let newMaxY = maxElement(yLabels!)
        if min.y == nil || newMinY < min.y { min.y = newMinY }
        if max.y == nil || newMaxY > max.y { max.y = newMaxY }
    }

    if min.x == nil { min.x = 0 }
    if min.y == nil { min.y = 0 }
    if max.x == nil { max.x = 0 }
    if max.y == nil { max.y = 0 }

    return (min: (x: min.x!, y: min.y!), max: (x: max.x!, max.y!))

}

private func scaleValuesOnXAxis(values: Array<Float>) -> Array<Float> {
    let width = Float(drawingWidth)

    var factor: Float
    if max.x - min.x == 0 { factor = 0 }
    else { factor = width / (max.x - min.x) }

    let scaled = values.map { factor * ($0 - self.min.x) }
    return scaled
}

private func scaleValuesOnYAxis(values: Array<Float>) -> Array<Float> {

    let height = Float(drawingHeight)
    var factor: Float
    if max.y - min.y == 0 { factor = 0 }
    else { factor = height / (max.y - min.y) }

    let scaled = values.map { Float(self.topInset) + height - factor * ($0 - self.min.y) }

    return scaled
}

private func scaleValueOnYAxis(value: Float) -> Float {

    let height = Float(drawingHeight)
    var factor: Float
    if max.y - min.y == 0 { factor = 0 }
    else { factor = height / (max.y - min.y) }

    let scaled = Float(self.topInset) + height - factor * (value - min.y)
    return scaled
}

private func getZeroValueOnYAxis() -> Float {
    if min.y > 0 {
        return scaleValueOnYAxis(min.y)
    }
    else {
        return scaleValueOnYAxis(0)
    }

}

// MARK: - Drawings

private func isVerticalSegmentAboveXAxis(yValues: Array<Float>) -> Bool {

    // YValues are "reverted" from top to bottom, so min is actually the maxz
    let min = maxElement(yValues)
    let zero = getZeroValueOnYAxis()

    return min <= zero

}

private func drawLine(#xValues: Array<Float>, yValues: Array<Float>, seriesIndex: Int) -> CAShapeLayer {

    let isAboveXAxis = isVerticalSegmentAboveXAxis(yValues)
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, CGFloat(xValues.first!), CGFloat(yValues.first!))

    for i in 1..<yValues.count {
        let y = yValues[i]
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, CGFloat(xValues[i]), CGFloat(y))
    }

    var lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    lineLayer.frame = self.bounds
    lineLayer.path = path

    if isAboveXAxis {
        lineLayer.strokeColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.above.CGColor
    }
    else {
        lineLayer.strokeColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.below.CGColor
    }
    lineLayer.fillColor = nil
    lineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    lineLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel

    self.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)

    layerStore.append(lineLayer)

    return lineLayer
}

private func drawArea(#xValues: Array<Float>, yValues: Array<Float>, seriesIndex: Int) {
    let isAboveXAxis = isVerticalSegmentAboveXAxis(yValues)
    let area = CGPathCreateMutable()
    let zero = CGFloat(getZeroValueOnYAxis())

    CGPathMoveToPoint(area, nil, CGFloat(xValues[0]), zero)

    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(area, nil, CGFloat(xValues[i]), CGFloat(yValues[i]))
    }

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(area, nil, CGFloat(xValues.last!), zero)

    var areaLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    areaLayer.frame = self.bounds
    areaLayer.path = area
    areaLayer.strokeColor = nil
    if isAboveXAxis {
        areaLayer.fillColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.above.colorWithAlphaComponent(areaAlphaComponent).CGColor
    }
    else {
        areaLayer.fillColor = series[seriesIndex].colors.below.colorWithAlphaComponent(areaAlphaComponent).CGColor
    }
    areaLayer.lineWidth = 0

    self.layer.addSublayer(areaLayer)

    layerStore.append(areaLayer)
}

private func drawAxes() {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, axesColor.CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5)

    // horizontal axis at the bottom
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, drawingHeight + topInset)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, drawingWidth, drawingHeight + topInset)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    // horizontal axis at the top
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, drawingWidth, 0)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    // horizontal axis when y = 0
    if min.y < 0 && max.y > 0 {
        let y = CGFloat(getZeroValueOnYAxis())
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, drawingWidth, y)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }

    // vertical axis on the left
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, drawingHeight + topInset)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)


    // vertical axis on the right
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, drawingWidth, 0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, drawingWidth, drawingHeight + topInset)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

}
```

Any hint or help as to where I need to implement this would be massively appreciated.

And I apologize for the awfulness that is this question begging for help or a direction.

Comment: What about SwiftCharts? https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts You just have to create an array with the values you need and pass it to the axis.